# table guava database

Tags: java, sql, guava

I want as column key   ​​ordered but it did not work,There are other solutions!!

I need sorted colnnes to comaparer with a also hashmap sorte

### this is my code

```
public class AllRatingsOp {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Table<Integer, Integer, Integer> table = HashBasedTable.create();
     //List<Integer,Integer> lst1 = new List<Integer,Integer>();

    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bd_recommandation";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "";


    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM vote order by id;");
        while (rs.next()) {

            Integer idoperateur = rs.getInt(1);//colomn 2
            Integer id = rs.getInt(2);
            Integer vote = rs.getInt(3);
            table.put(idoperateur, id, vote);

        }
        System.out.println(table);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

i need your help thnx

Comment: `HashBasedTable` is like a `HashMap`: it inherently lacks order.

Comment: but in requet sql i do oreder By but not work

Comment: Yes, so?  You took the results and put it in an unordered data structure.  You took the order away.

Comment: did you try with `SELECT * FROM vote order by id DESC` or `SELECT * FROM vote order by id ASC` ?

Comment: @YCF_L the query is irrelevant: the lack of order comes from the structure in which the results are stored.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, you have raison

Comment: One unrelated piece of advice: Never swallow exceptions, unless you want to spend days with trivial problems. There's nothing as stupid as an empty catch block. Adding the exception to the `throws` clause is right 99% of time.

Comment: @maaartinus thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a [`TreeBasedTable`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeBasedTable.html) instead of a `HashBasedTable`:

> Implementation of Table whose row keys and column keys are ordered by their natural ordering or by supplied comparators.